# trying to iterate dataframe under condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to get a return in terms of my trading logic in stock market

the code that I wrote was intended to print entry price, exit price, return

Here is the code that I tried:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    # (첫날+100)이전은 계산을 할 수 없으므로 제외
    if index < 100:
        continue
        
    # condition to define 80/20 candle pattern and market timing
    long = (row['close'] - row['low'])/(row['high'] - row['low']) < 0.2
    short = (row['close'] - row['low'])/(row['high'] - row['low']) > 0.8
    long_con = (row['close']) <= 1.05*(row['100SMA'])
    short_con = (row['close']) >= 0.95*(row['100SMA'])
    
    while (long & long_con)|short:
        if (long & long_con):
            entry_price = row['close']
        elif short:
            exit_price = row['close']
            rt = ((exit_price - entry_price)/entry_price - 1) *100
        
            print(f'{df.index} entry price {entry_price} exit price {exit_price} return {rt}%')
```

and it the output says the entry_price variable is not defined?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 1>()
     16 elif short:
     17     exit_price = row['close']
---> 18     rt = ((exit_price - entry_price)/entry_price - 1) *100
     20     print(f'{df.index} entry price {entry_price} exit price {exit_price} return {rt}%')

NameError: name 'entry_price' is not defined
```

Comment: couple of things, you're defining the entry_price in IF condition, and using in Else, where it doesn't exist. Also, your line is error is like indented, and needs to be de-indented along with the print statement. Lastly, rt is using both entry_price and exit_price, so both should be initialized prior to be used

Comment: @Naveed what I don't understand is I need to use if and elif to create entry_price and exit_price under the condition. How can I write code under the condition and calculate rt at the same time?

Comment: the line in error executes under the elif condition. Indentation matters in python, so that the line in error needs to de-indent and align with the if-elif level.